# Trouble adding date to tcsh history

Tags: command-history, tcsh

I'm trying to add the date to my tcsh history information and I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.  The tcsh man page reads like this for the history setting:

> The first word indicates the number of history events to save.  The optional second word (+) indicates the format in which history is printed;  if  not given, `%h\t%T\t%R\n' is used.  The format sequences are described below  under  prompt;  note  the variable meaning of `%R'.  Set to`100' by default.

I've tried the following put a line in my `.cshrc` file using what they say is the default format, but I get an error every time I source.  Here is what I've tried (with the resulting error in brackets):

`set history = 2000 '%h\t%T\t%R\n'` *[set: Variable name must begin with a letter.]*
`set history = 2000 %h\t%T\t%R\n` *[set: Variable name must begin with a letter.]*
`set history = 2000 $DATE='%h\t%T\t%R\n'` *[DATE: Undefined variable.]*
`set history = 2000 $FORMAT='%h\t%T\t%R\n'` *[FORMAT: Undefined variable.]*
`set history = 2000 $TIME='%h\t%T\t%R\n'` *[TIME: Undefined variable.]*

The following doesn't give me a source error, it gives me a `history: Badly formed number.` error when I try to use history:

```
set history = '2000 %h\t%T\t%R\n'
```

I'm obviously just thrashing around here, I don't have a lot of experience with modifying the `.cshrc` file.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Try with this syntax:

```
set history=(2000 "%h\t%T\t%R\n")
```

To get a full date:

```
set history=(2000 "%h %D/%W/%Y %T %R\n")
```

Demo:

```
$ set history=(2000 "%h %D/%W/%Y %T %R\n")
$ history 
     1 20/05/2011 6:27 set prompt="$ "
     2 20/05/2011 6:27 set history= ( 2000 "%h %D/%W/%Y %T %R\n" )
     3 20/05/2011 6:27 history
```